# using topoJSON in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, topojson

I'm trying to plot (using ggplot) a topoJSON file I generated from https://pitchinteractiveinc.github.io/tilegrams/.

I used the code below to try to plot the example npr 1-to-1 data:

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal) 
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
map = readOGR("data/npr.json", "tiles")
map_df <- fortify(map)
gg = ggplot(data = map_df,  aes(long,lat, group=group))
gg = gg + geom_polygon(colour="gray65", size=1.0)
print(gg)
```

The result is not right.

[image]

I've tried plotting this with geom_map, and tried adding coord_equal and coord_map without impact.

I also tried to plot a single polygon and got the image below.  Perhaps it suggests that points of the polygon are in incorrect order?  Anyone have an idea on how to correct?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the issues seems to be in the conversion done by the readOGR.  I imported the json manually and extract the polygons and it worked fine.

[image]

Comment: You may want to give the `geojsonio` package a go as well (+ use `coord_map()` or `coord_equal()` with that  resultant cartogram. R also has a `statebins` package that you may find useful.